# Site Wide Discount Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, e-commerce, discount

Looking for a script that applies a discount to every product in my woocommerce store

So every product no variables, just 10% off everything.

And it shows the regular price, then the sale price with the sale badge

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price',     'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price',     'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
function assign_tier_pricing( $price, $product ) {
    $price *= 0.5; // Set all prices for simple products to 50%     off.     
    return $price;   
}
```

the above code does nothing when added to functions file.

Answer (score 0):

```html
// Generating dynamically the product "regular price"
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_dynamic_regular_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_dynamic_regular_price', 10, 2 );
function custom_dynamic_regular_price( $regular_price, $product ) {
    if( empty($regular_price) || $regular_price == 0 )
        return $product->get_price();
    else
        return $regular_price;
}


// Generating dynamically the product "sale price"
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'custom_dynamic_sale_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'custom_dynamic_sale_price', 10, 2 );
function custom_dynamic_sale_price( $sale_price, $product ) {
    $rate = 0.8;
    if( empty($sale_price) || $sale_price == 0 )
        return $product->get_regular_price() * $rate;
    else
        return $sale_price;
};

// Displayed formatted regular price + sale price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_dynamic_sale_price_html', 20, 2 );
function custom_dynamic_sale_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) return $price_html;

    $price_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ), wc_get_price_to_display(  $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) ) ) . $product->get_price_suffix();

    return $price_html;
}
```